# flex 4.5 + wbservice .net

Tags: asp.net, flex4

Im working on a example that im trying to use a webservice make it in .net c# and i have a some questions. I have a method in webservice like that:

```
 public string login(string user, string pass)

     {
         //string msg = "";
         string res = "";
         person n = new person(user, pass);

         if (n.login())
         {

             Session["user"] = Server.HtmlEncode(u);

             setTimeOutLogIn(u);


             res = u;
         }
         else
         {
            // msg = "Error";
         }

         return res;
}
```

now with this I return a string with a unique user for flex to make a state of user.

my doubt is how can I work properly on flex with session?

Other question and problem having here, and is a big one:
when is made any request to webservice the flex only answer the second ask. for example:

```
 public function LogUser()
            {
            var name:String=Login.text;
            var pass:String=Password.text;

                Service.login.send(name, pass);
                checkLogin();
            }

    public function checkLogin():Boolean
            {
            var boll:Boolean= new Boolean;
            Service.checkLogin.send(util);
            boll = Service.checkLogin.lastResult;
            if(boll==false)
                {
                Llogout.visible=false;
                Lregist.visible=true;
                Llogin.visible=true;
                Luser.visible=false;
                currentState="default";
                } 
            else
                {
                Llogin.visible=false;
                Llogout.visible=true;
                Lregist.visible=false;
                Luser.visible=true;
                Luser.text=util;
                currentState="default";
                }
            return boll;
            }
```

```
        <s:operation name="login"> </s:operation>
        <s:operation name="checkLogin" result="checkLog()"></s:operation>
    </s:WebService>
```

this simple operation only respond rightly  for the second time.

Any thoughts?

Sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 0):

Webservice calls are not like website calls.  You will not be able to set a user session that will persist and only be available to your users session.  You may want to check out [FlorineFX](http://www.fluorinefx.com/) I dont think it will do exactly what you want but I know you can do some of this stuff and interact with the asp.net more like a website.  We used this for several projects a couple years ago.